# Troubles With SSL when use Google Maps API on SAP

Tags: google-maps, abap

I have a geolocalizer develop using Google Maps API on SAP and connect to Google Maps WS by url with XML mode but when I get the response I recieve the error I show below. SAP Application Server have installed some CA (even the Google Internet Authority G3) but develop still doesn't work. Have any idea what can I do to solve this? I'll appreciate it.

```
500 SSL Peer Certificate Untrusted

SSL handshake with maps.googleapis.com:443 failed: SSSLERR_PEER_CERT_UNTRUSTED (-102)


The peer's X.509 Certificate (chain) is untrusted

SapSSLSessionStartNB()==SSSLERR_PEER_CERT_UNTRUSTED
  SSL:SSL_read() failed  (536872221/0x2000051d)
  => "Failed to verify peer certificate. Peer not trusted."
  SSL:SSL_get_state()==0x2131 "TLS read server certificate B"
  SSL NI-hdl 90: local=10.0.4.146:25023  peer=172.217.8.10:443
  cli SSL session PSE "/usr/sap/SED/DVEBMGS00/sec/SAPSSLC.pse"
  session ciphersuites=HIGH:MEDIUM:+e3DES:!aNULL
  Client SSL_CTX 7f0d8006f830 pvflags=128 (TLSv1.0)
  Target Hostname="maps.googleapis.com"
>> ---- SecuSSL ErrStack: ----
0x2000051d | SAPCRYPTOLIB | SSL_read
SSL API error
Failed to verify peer certificate. Peer not trusted.
0xa0600203 | SSL | ssl3_read_bytes
Peer not trusted
0xa0600203 | SSL | ssl3_connect
Peer not trusted
0xa0600203 | SSL | ssl3_get_server_certificate
Peer not trusted
0xa0600203 | SSL | ssl3_decode_server_certificate
Peer not trusted
0xa0600203 | SSL | ssl_verify_peer_certificates
Peer not trusted
0xa0600203 | SSL | ssl_cert_checker_verify_certificates
Peer not trusted
0xa0600203 | SSL | ssl_cert_checker_verify_certificates
Peer not trusted
Certificate:
 Certificate:
  Subject:                              CN=*.googleapis.com, O=Google LLC, L=Mountain View, SP=California, C=US
  Issuer:                               CN=Google Internet Authority G3, O=Google Trust Services, C=US
  Serial Number:                        7C:C5:3D:5F:59:B7:CC:33
 Verification result:
  Status:                              Not successful
  SignerStatus:                        Not successful
  SignerVerificationResult:
   Status:                              Not successful
   Validity:                            Successful
   BasicConstraints:                    Successful
   KeyUsage:                            Successful
   ObjectStatus:                        Not successful
   SignerCert:
    Certificate:
     Subject:                              CN=Google Internet Authority G3, O=Google Trust Services, C=US
     Issuer:                               CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2
     Serial Number:                        01:E3:A9:30:1C:FC:72:06:38:3F:9A:53:1D
    Verification result:
     Status:                              Not successful
     SignerStatus:                        Not successful
     SignerVerificationResult:            None

<< ---------------------------



Error: -48 
Version: 7490 
Component: ICM 
Date/Time: Mon Nov 5 16:46:06 2018  
Module: icxxconn.c 
Line: 2240 
Server: gserpsed_SED_00 
Error Tag: {000006e1}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to change the ciphersuites cf [note 510007 - Setting up SSL on Application Server ABAP](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/510007)

Comment: Hi Sandra, basis area told me ciphersuite is already installed that's why I think is a certificate problem

Comment: "installed" ? You mean it's setup with the right value. You may need to change its value depending on the web sites you are contacting and also when these websites change the way they encrypt and authenticate (cf [cipher suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_suite)). We had to change the ciphersuite value because GitHub had changed the way they encrypt/authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

Your log said that, certificate chain not found in SSL Client (Stanadart). You need to check root certificate(s) add to to this cert library in t-code STRUST. SAP Netweaver can have multiple cert list, one of them can setted as default. If you not determine it in your code, default one used.

[image: strust]

Answer (score 0):

There is no details on which SAP system you are using but the idea is, if you want to communicate with some external API;

For R/3:

1. URL's should be whitelisted,
2. Certificates of the target system should be installed in your system.

Check out these notes:

- [1832480 - How to implement Twitter API for CRM Interaction Center](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1832480)
- [1832481 - How to implement Facebook API for CRM Interaction Center](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1832481)